# Tensorflow 2.0/Keras: Using a SparseTensor as the input to a Conv2D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to build a network using the Keras library of Tensorflow 2.0 which

1. Takes a `SparseTensor`as input, and
2. Uses `Conv2D` as its first hidden layer.

My motivation behind using this architecture is as follows:

1. My inputs consist of samples of 2D geospatial data.
2. Because each sample uses 2 channels, my overall input tensors are 4-dimensional (i.e., one dimension for the sample, 2 dimensions for *X* and *Y*, 1 dimension for the channel).
3. Each data sample is too large to fit into memory as provided.
4. However, each sample is sparse enough that by switching the overall representation of our input from a 4D NumPy `ndarray` to a 4D `SparseTensor`, we were able to reduce the number of points we needed to explicitly define in our input tensor by around 99.8%.

Unfortunately, I keep hitting the following error when I try and train my model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py", line 318, in assert_same_structure
    expand_composites)
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([204, 9808, 5077, 2]), tf.float32)

Second structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("conv2d_input:0", shape=(None, 9808, 5077, 2), dtype=float32)

More specifically: Substructure "type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([204, 9808, 5077, 2]), tf.float32)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("conv2d_input:0", shape=(None, 9808, 5077, 2), dtype=float32)" is not

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_network.py", line 137, in <module>
    callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, lr_callback])
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 547, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 594, in _process_inputs
    steps=steps)
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2497, in _standardize_user_data
    nest.assert_same_structure(a, b, expand_composites=True)
  File "C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\nest.py", line 325, in assert_same_structure
    % (str(e), str1, str2))
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([204, 9808, 5077, 2]), tf.float32)

Second structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("conv2d_input:0", shape=(None, 9808, 5077, 2), dtype=float32)

More specifically: Substructure "type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([204, 9808, 5077, 2]), tf.float32)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("conv2d_input:0", shape=(None, 9808, 5077, 2), dtype=float32)" is not
Entire first structure:
.
Entire second structure:
.
```

My model is built and trained using the following code:

```
def build_model(x_conv_dim, y_conv_dim, channels):
  """
  Building the neural network model (architecture)
  Returns: model -- NN model including the layers, parameter initialization, and activation
  """
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        input_shape = (x_conv_dim, y_conv_dim, channels),
        filters = 1,
        kernel_size = 300,
        strides = 10,
        padding = 'valid',
        activation = 'relu',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal',
        bias_initializer = 'zeros'),
      # tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1, trainable=True, epsilon=BATCH_NORM_EPSILON),
      # tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(Y_train_orig.shape[0], kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='zeros'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1, trainable=True, epsilon=BATCH_NORM_EPSILON),
  ])

  model.compile(loss='mae',
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['mse'])

  return model

# Each X value is a SparseTensor.
X_train_orig, Y_train_orig, X_dev_orig, Y_dev_orig, X_test_orig, Y_test_orig = utils.load_dataset()

# Building the model
model = build_model(
  x_conv_dim = X_train_orig.shape[1],
  y_conv_dim = X_train_orig.shape[2],
  channels = X_train_orig.shape[3])

# Training model.
history = model.fit(
    x = X_train_orig,
    y = Y_train_orig.T,
    epochs = 100,
    batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, lr_callback])
```

Can anyone recommend a way to make this architecture work, and/or spot what I'm doing wrong with the approach above?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Tried reproducing your code and got the error, `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'load_dataset'`. Can you share the complete code. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?